# All product quantity set 0 in magento 2 through query

Tags: php, magento2

How can we set all product have stock(quantity) zero in magento 2. we have more than 1M product so we are not able to chagne instant quantity through admin panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Go to Magento Database and fire this two query

1. Update `cataloginventory_stock_item` SET `qty` = 0.0000,`is_in_stock` =
   0,`stock_status_changed_auto` = 1,`low_stock_date` = NOW()
2. Update `cataloginventory_stock_status` SET `qty` =
   0.0000,`stock_status` = 0